# UITableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath not being called on first tap

Tags: uitableview, ios5, didselectrowatindexpath

I'm having an issue with UITableView's didSelectRowAtIndexPath of ios 5, which is correct in ios 4.

The first time I tap any row in the table, the method does not get called. Once I select another row, it call the didSelectRowAtIndexPath, but pass the last indexPath.

I've set tableView.delegate already, and it can run correctly in ios4.

```
MainView.xib
UITabBarController
     --UINavigationController
         --**UITableViewController**
```

Any suggestions?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 10;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"%d",indexPath.row);
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code?  Are you sure you haven't implemented didDeselectRowAtIndexPath instead?

Comment: I didn't implement deselect. Thanks.

Comment: This should work no problem. Is this class a subclass of UITableViewController? If it is than there is no need to set delegate in viewDidLoad method cos it's already assigned. Otherwise add delegate in class .h file in brackets <UITableViewDelegate>.

Comment: @AnnaKarenina - I hit this issue this morning, Anna Karenina has saved my skin again - thanks :)

Comment: @AnnaKarenina - Thank you! *So* tricky, especially since 'deselect' precedes 'select' alphabetically.

Comment: possible duplicate of [UITableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath: not being called on first tap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2106292/uitableview-didselectrowatindexpath-not-being-called-on-first-tap)

Comment: Being working with table views and controllers on daily basis and just faced the very same issue. Thanks to @AnnaKarenina I know the reason, did autocomplete with didDeselectRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: is this issue solved? can you please answer (your own) the question, so we can close this!?

Comment: this work fine on my side and work on first tap and give correct ans

Comment: Another Gesture recognizer on the view May be the reason.

Answer (score 34):

You may have implemented (notice the **Deselect**): `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath`

...hence the trigger upon selecting a new cell which deselects the first one, and logging indexPath as the first one as well.

**SOLUTION:** `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

yeah, they look super similar, and it doesn't help that `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` is the first method Xcode's autocomplete selects most of the time.

**FULL CODE:**

```
// right
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {}
```

Comment: thanks! was wondering why my alert view was showing the details of the last selected row!

Comment: Just came here for a very similar issue I was having with my iOS8 Swift project. This is exactly what I had done. Thanks!

Comment: Would help a bit if you **bold** Select and Deselect. It takes a bit of staring to see it.

Comment: Thanks, 30 minutes wasted; could have been more though

Answer (score 1):

Please, try to change your `-viewDidLoad` to the code below (insert last line). Tell me about the results.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this has been answered but I was running with this issue and just like "Anna Karenina" commented above. Make sure that you pay close attention to detail.

This is cause by you implementing the DEselect

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

This will cause the first click not to work but following clicks and any other cell will work as expected.

**Solution**: make sure you pay attention and use `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

hope that helps and like I mention before this was solved by "Anna Karenina"

Answer (score 0):

Please Connect Delegate from Xib to Files Owners. Then Try it Will Work.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in your **viewDidLoad** method

```
[self.tableView reloadData]
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a UIGestureRecognizer on the view inside of the storyboard. I had to remove it and it worked like normal.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem when passing data to another VC. I solved it by switching to a manual segue from the Table VC to the detail VC.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        selectedData = data[indexPath.row]

        performSegue(withIdentifier: "Detail", sender: self)
}
```

Comment: how that should solve it if the didselect method is being called at all ? please help me to understand more thanks :)