# Why is -didDeselectRowAtIndexPath not being called?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I created a fresh project (Xcode 4, Master-Detail application) just to see if I'm doing something wrong, but I still have the same problem. I want to call `-reloadData` when the user **deselects** a cell, so this is my code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    [tableView reloadData];
}

-(NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    return indexPath;
}
```

The problem is that `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` and `willDeselectRowAtIndexPath` don't seem to be called. Is this the expected behavior? The docs for `tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:` state

> Tells the delegate that the specified row is now deselected.

so I guess that it should work as I thought.

Comment: Did you correctly set the delegate for your UITableView?

Comment: did you specify the tables delegate? and did you allow users to select cells at all?

Comment: Yes and yes. The selection works as it should, the de-selection is the problem..

Answer (score 25, accepted):

the documentation of [`tableView:willDeselectRowAtIndexPath:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006942-CH3-SW10) also says that

> This method is only called if there is an existing selection when the
>   user tries to select a different row. The delegate is sent this method
>   for the previously selected row. You can use
>   **UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone** to disable the appearance of the
>   cell highlight on touch-down.

It not worked for we when I used `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone`.

Comment: But this is for `willDeselectRowAtIndexPath`, not for `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` right?? Could it be that both are fired only after a different cell gets selected?

Comment: This is for both,  check [UITableViewDelegate Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/)

Comment: Ok, but if we forget about `willDeselectRowAtIndexPath`, it seems that I'm not doing something wrong, and that `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` is just not working the way I want it, right?

Comment: This answer looks wrong. `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone` DOES NOT prevent `willDeselectRowAtIndexPath` and `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` being called.

Answer (score 55):

If you call `deselectRowAtIndexPath:animated:`, the delegate methods `tableView:willDeselectRowAtIndexPath:` and `tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:` message are not sent.

Comment: What about gesture recognizer? Will that be executed if we use `deselectRowAtIndexPath:animated:`?

Comment: tableView:willDeselectRowAtIndexPath: also not called. I am using TableViewcontroller

Comment: Wow Great Thanks Only this solution is working for me

Answer (score 12):

One other quirk that I've found — in IOS 5.1, at any rate — is that if you call `reloadData` on the table, you won't get `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` for any selected rows. In my case, I adjust the cell layout slightly depending on whether it's selected or not, so I needed to manually do that work prior to reloading the table data.

Comment: You are right. `reloadData` makes tableView "forget" the selected rows. Yet there is a quick fix for that: just reload specific rows by calling `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withAnimation:`

Answer (score 10):

I know this is an old question but I just ran into the same problem.

If you use

```
[tableView reloadData]
```

Then The table data is reloaded and no rows are selected behind the scenes - meaning

only

```
didSelectRowAtIndexPath
```

is ever called. I hope this helps someone who comes across this problem.

Answer (score 6):

A clean way of solving this problem is to do the following:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    // Do your cell setup work here...

    //If your cell should be selected...
    if cellShouldBeSelected {
        tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.None)
    }

    return cell
}
```

This solves this entire problem of a cell not responding to being deselected after a `tableView.reloadData()`call happens.

Comment: I don't particular like Swift, but your advice _really_ helped me out, thanks a lot!

Comment: Nice!  Thanks for this.

Answer (score 4):

When any cell is selected the first time, the `-[UITableViewDelegate tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:]` method is not called, but the `-[UITableViewDelegate tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:]`. Just after selecting one more cell, the `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` is called right after the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

**This is OK.**

But if you have to show a cell as selected at the begining, (e.q. using `UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark`), then, after selecting another cell you probably want the `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` method being called the first time, to deselect the previous cell.

**The solution!**

You have to call the `-[UITableView selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:]` in the `-[UITableViewDataSource tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:]` to notify that a wanted cell is already selected.

**Objective-C**

```
#pragma mark - UITableViewDelegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    // saving the current selected row
    SelectedRow = indexPath.row;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}

#pragma mark - UITableViewDataSource

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }

    // preventing selection style
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    cell.textLabel.text = "Some text";

    if (indexPath.row == SelectedRow) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        // just wanted to make it selected, but it also can scroll to the selected position
        [tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

**Swift 3.1**

```
// MARK: - UITableViewDelegate

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)!
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.checkmark
    selectedRow = indexPath.row
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)!
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.none
}

// MARK: - UITableViewDataSource

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")

    // preventing selection style
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none

    cell.textLabel?.text = "some text"

    if (indexPath.row == selectedRow) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.checkmark
        // just wanted to make it selected, but it also can scroll to the selected position
        tableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.none)
    }

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You just have to set the selection to be "Multiple Selection" as Xcode allow you to deselect the cells in this mode only.

[Xcode Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4LOp.png)

Answer (score 1):

Set `allowsMultipleSelection` for that tableview to `TRUE`

```
  self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = YES;
```

Answer (score 1):

For me it's started working by adding ->`super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)`

```
override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
   super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)//This was missing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's just simple mistake!
Why don't you use following:

```
[self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
```

Instead of using just "tableView" in that line? 
I guess, and pretty sure that above line would give you the solution! 
 hope this helped you, if you looked back at your old question!!!
Kudos! :)

Comment: I don't think this is the problem, tableView refers to self.tableView anyway. Try it, you will learn something.

Comment: :? ok, sorry if I have mislead then! I would try and post the findings as a comment here!Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to set `allowsMultipleSelection` is `true` and set `delegate` by below code

```
self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
self.tableView.delegate = self
```

If you use `tableView.reloadData()` in `didSelectRowAt` delegate method, remove this.

in your custom cell, use selected method.

```
override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
   super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
   //write your code here for selection method
}
```

By this method, your cell state is selected. If you again click on selected cell, then didDeSelect delegate method will call automatically.

Answer (score 0):

One source of this issue is setting `isSelected` directly on the table view cell, rather than telling the table view to select the cell via `selectRow(at:animated:scrollPosition:)` or deselect it via `deselectRow(at:animated:)`.

The cell's `isSelected` property is not the source of truth that the table view uses to determine whether to call the delegate's `didDeselect` method (although a cell whose `isSelected` is set *does* seem to prevent the table view from calling the delegate's `didSelect` method—meaning that the cell can get in a state where it is impossible to select or deselect via the UI).