# tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath: not called until first user-initiated selection and deselection

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` with four cells, in single selection mode. When the view is first loaded, I programmatically select one of the cells using `-selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:` based on a stored preference. After this, the user can interact with the table.

The methods `-tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath:` and `-tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` are called on my table view delegate every time the user taps any cell. However, `-tableView:willDeselectRowAtIndexPath:` and `-tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:` (that's DEselect) don't start being called until the user manually taps that first programmatically selected cell.

Any idea why this might be happening? Are there any workarounds besides manually calling `-[UITableView selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:]` for every cell except the one that the user tapped?

Comment: You trying to achieve deselection of `UITableViewCell` right after selecting it?

Comment: Not quite. One cell (call it _cellA_) is selected programmatically. I want the user to be able to deselect _cellA_ by tapping another cell, but in practice this doesn't work until the user actually taps _cellA_ himself.

Comment: Yes, I had the same problem. You need to call the `selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:` method to set the status to selected. Check my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/44097559/1600061

Answer (score 1):

If you do invoke [UITableView selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:] too soon and you are using a UITableViewController, you probably have conflict with the UIViewController clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear (defaults to YES). Try setting self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO; in your viewDidLoad

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for comment so I'm posting this as an answer.

Just created test project with tableView. I call `[UITableView selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:]` on `viewDidLoad` and I have one cell selected. Then I'm selecting another cell (without deselecting first one).

I have this output:

```
[SDTVTViewController tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath:]    
[SDTVTViewController tableView:willDeselectRowAtIndexPath:]    
[SDTVTViewController tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:]    
[SDTVTViewController tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:]
```

And I have first cell deselected and second one selected.

I have no idea, why it's not working in your code. When you're calling `[UITableView selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:]` and can you post code of `UITableViewDelegate` methods that you've implemented?

Answer (score 0):

I was wrapping my initial data source updates and `-selectRowAtIndexPath:...` calls in

```
[_tableView beginUpdates];
// ...
[_tableView endUpdates];
```

Apparently, like `-reloadData`, this clears the current selection (not sure if that's by design). I moved the call to `-selectRowAtIndexPath:...` to after `-endUpdates` and now everything works as intended.