# didDeselectRowAtIndexPath only called after pressing another cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

So here's the thing:

I implemented a UITableViewController with a custom cell..
Then i replaced the automatic segue `cell to viewcontroller` (storyboard)  with `viewcontroller to viewcontroller`.

Code from my UITableViewController:

```
// MARK: - Tableview managment

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var lobbycell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("lobbycell") as! LobbyTableViewCell
        let row = indexPath.row
        if let channel = lobbies[row].lobbyName {
            lobbycell.lobbynameLabel.text = channel
        }
        if let usercount = lobbies[row].users?.count {
            lobbycell.usercountLabel.text = "Anzahl Spieler: \(usercount)"
        }
        if let host = lobbies[row].host?.username {
            lobbycell.hostnameLabel.text = "Host: \(host)"
        }
        return lobbycell
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return lobbies.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let selectedLobby = lobbies[indexPath.row]
        var loading = MBProgressHUD.showHUDAddedTo(self.view, animated: true)
        PFLobby.joinLobbyInBackgroundWithBlock(selectedLobby, user: PFUser.currentUser()!) { (success, error) -> Void in
            loading.hide(true)
            if success {
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("joinLobby", sender: self)
            } else {

            }

        }
    }
```

Now here's the problem:
If I click on a cell it's going to get gray (like selected) but won't call the `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath`func..
Only If I click on another cell it's going to call the `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath`with the gray (like selected) cell's indexPath.

[image: The stuck cell]

Comment: did you mean/expect to use `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and not `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath`? (Select vs Deselect)

Comment: Omg xD
Of course.. sorry, auto-completion thank you..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you confused with `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath`?

The latter will only be called if it's **deselected**, hence why it's called after you select another cell.

If you want to call the `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath`, then add the method `deselectRowAtIndexPath` in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and it will deselect right way.

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behavior. `tableView(_:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:)` will only be called after another cell is selected.

If you want, it is possible to intercept the selection event in `tableView(:_willSelectRowAtIndexPath:)`:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> NSIndexPath? {

    if let selectedIndex = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() where selectedIndex == indexPath {
        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
        return nil
    }

    return indexPath
}
```

The index path returned by this method will be selected. If you return `nil`, nothing will get selected.

Comment: Yes, but if you have an selected cell at the initialization, then it should be called at the first cell selection. Here is how: http://stackoverflow.com/a/44097559/1600061