# Not able to get single selection checkbox

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton

I have made a tableviewcell and it has a button within it. I connected the IBAction of the button in the tableviewcell.swift class. Then I made a delegate and accessed the button touch action in the viewcontroller class like so..

```
func optionTap(cell: SlideUpTableViewCell) {
    if let indexPath = tableview?.indexPath(for: cell) {
     }
}
```

But what I want to achieve is, I want just one checkbox button to be selected at a time. I have 3 rows and now I can tap on each of the 3 buttons while I wanted to tap on only 1 button at a time. i.e. if I tap the  button on the 1st cell and then tap on the button in the 2nd cell, then the 1st cell button should be automatically deselected. In short, how normal single selection works...

I have tried this...But it doesn't work...

```
   func optionTap(cell: SlideUpTableViewCell) {
if let indexPath = tableview?.indexPath(for: cell) {

  if selectedArrayIndex.contains(indexPath.row) {

    selectedArrayIndex.remove(at: selectedArrayIndex.index(of: indexPath.row)!)
    cell.checkBobButton.tintColor = ThemeManager.current().inactiveGrayColor
    cell.checkBobButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "circle_stroke"), for: .normal)

  } else {
    selectedArrayIndex.append(indexPath.row)
    cell.checkBobButton.tintColor = ThemeManager.current().secondaryColor
    cell.checkBobButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "circle_tick"), for: .normal)

  }

 }
}
```

**EDIT 1:**  This is the cellForRow..

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: SlideUpTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellID) as! SlideUpTableViewCell
    cell.delegate = self
    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    cell.headingLabel.text = self.arrData[indexPath.row].heading
    cell.subHeadingLabel.text = self.arrData[indexPath.row].subHeading

    return cell
  }
```

**EDIT 2** This is how the UI will look..

[image]

Comment: add some additional code

Comment: ok @Anbu.Karthik..But that's what I'm confused about..:)

Comment: show your cellforRow

Comment: I have edited the question with the cellForRow..@Anbu.Karthik

Comment: @asd2, for single selection use didSelectRowAtIndex path function.

Comment: where will you write the code for `optionTap`

Comment: the function `func optionTap(cell: SlideUpTableViewCell)..` gets the button taps @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: @asd2, actually we have didSelectRowAtIndex path and didDeselectRowAtIndex path functions for single selections. So use these UITableViewDelegates.

Comment: Actually @iOS the project required a custom btn..that's why..

Comment: ok @Anbu.Karthik...thanks..:)

Comment: Your buttons are in same cell or are they in diff cell? Does all button connected to same IBAction or they have dirref?

Comment: I have just one cell in which I have the button. Only thing is I have 3 rows..@dahiya_boy

Comment: @asd2  You have 3 cells (by dequeue) and each cell have 1 button and you need to select one out three at a time? Show your UI for better clearance.

Comment: I have edited the question with a pic of the UI @dahiya_boy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you don't need button actions. Follow below steps for easy & perfect coding :

1. Take a var in your controller `var selectedIndex = -1` // -1 if not any index in selected, if you wanted to select any option by default then change it accordingly.
2. Use `tableView` delegate method `didSelectRowAt indexPath`

   ```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){

       selectedIndex = indexPath.row
       myTblView.reloadData()

   }
   ```
3. Now to toggle btn just do this in `cellForRow`.

   ```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! Mycell

       :            
       cell.myBtn.isSelected = indexPath.row == selectedIndex
       :

       return cell
   }
   ```
4. Now in storyboard, assign button images for selected and default state.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It does work @dahiya_boy..But if a cell is selected, then if I tap on it again I want it to be deselected..

Comment: @asd2 In [tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614916-tableview) you have to do `selectedIndex = -1` and `tableview.reloadData()` *OR* you can add one extra condition in `didselect` for same functionality.

Comment: Sorry for the late response @dahiya_boy. I tried what you suggested..but `didDeselectRow...` is not called. The fourth answer in this link is the reason for that it seems.. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9819672/why-is-diddeselectrowatindexpath-not-being-called) . Could not yet come up with an extra condition in the `didselect`...

Comment: @asd2 I never used `didDeselect` so I was not updated.  You need to add condition in didSelect method. Its a simple toggle. You just need to maintain `selectedIndex` with condition and in last  reload tableView.

Comment: Sorry to bother @dahiya_boy..I did try..but couldn't come up with a solution...could u maybe mind suggesting a solution..?

Comment: @asd2 `if indexPath.row == selectedIndex { selectedIndex = -1 } else { selectedIndex = indexPath.row }` I think it should work.' Dont forget to reload data after this.

Answer (score 1):

```
 // if you want to use didselect or diddeselect than :

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
          if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)as? tableViewCell{
          cell.mRadioimage.image = UIImage(named: "radioCheckedImage")

            }
           }
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
          if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)as? tableViewCell{
          cell.mRadioimage.image = UIImage(named: "radioUnCheckedImage")
              }       
          }

        // don't forget to choose singleSelection
        // hope its work for you
```