# UITableView didSelectRowatIndexPath not called on single tap

Tags: ios, uitableview

Very very strange! It works everywhere but here:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
 MyViewController* cliente = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithModeAndClientId:2 c:cid];

            cliente.delegate                    = self;
            UINavigationController *n = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:cliente];

            n.navigationBarHidden     = NO;
            [[n navigationBar] setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlack];
            [self presentViewController:n animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

If I tap by a single click on the row, the `MyViewController` shows after seconds!
If I click twice, it shows rapidly!
In the Profiler, at single click nothing happens...
I have no `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` method.

Comment: Do you have any gesture recognisers or views on top of your cell that might be catching the taps?

Comment: No one...the same code works quickly if I use a    [[self navigationController] pushViewControllerRetro:schedaCliente];

Comment: Could your view controller initialisation code be blocking? Use Instruments -> Time Profiler to see if any of your code is taking a significantly long time.

Comment: I did it, but the time profile is of litte help, because it seems that  nothing is happening between two clicks :(

Comment: Firt hint: if I set animation:NO, the show is in real-time! (iOS7)

Answer (score 6):

The solution is to put on the main thread the loading of the second controller

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ 
       // Code here 
 });
```

Comment: Do you receive the tableView: didDeselectRowAtIndexPath: on a different thread than the main?

Comment: Sorry, I meant tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:. I just would like to see why the dispatch_async made this work. Either it is something to do with threading or with animations.

Comment: Well, didSelect is on the main thread, I suppose. How it could be on a different thread?

Answer (score 2):

Its issue of threading, when you tap a row in tableview it start a new thread so the presenting a view may take longer to show up on screen.

The solution is:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{ 
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        MyViewController* cliente = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithModeAndClientId:2 c:cid];

        cliente.delegate = self;
        UINavigationController *n = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:cliente];

        n.navigationBarHidden = NO;
        [[n navigationBar] setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlack];
        [self presentViewController:n animated:YES completion:nil];
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you by any chance putting a tableview inside a scroll view? If so the container scrollview is blocking the touch event to the inner table view. This fixed it for me:

```
self.myContainerScrollview.panGestureRecognizer.delaysTouchesBegan = true
```

Credit for the answer should go to the OP here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31040918/1455770

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. And it was hard to find. But it was because of following:

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        return nil;
}
```

You should return **indexPath**

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on my tableView(swift 4.2). After debugging and taking lots of time it appeared that table view has a boolean property named `allowsMultipleSelection`.

If `allowsMultipleSelection` is set to `true` the table view selection mechanism will change in a way that by selecting each cell the `tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` is called for the first time and by selecting the same cell for the second time the `tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:` is called.

This makes `tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` function to be called on the third selection for the same cell and so the result is double tap for calling `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`.

It means that if the number of times a cell tapped are odd (1, 3, 5, ...) then always `tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` will be called and if the number of times a cell tapped are even (2, 4, 6, ...) then always `tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:` will be called.

If you want the `tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` to be called on each selection for a cell then the tableView **multiple selection** has to be set `false`, `tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = false`.

By doing this, every time the cell is tapped `tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` will be called on table view and by selecting another cell `tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:` will be called for the **cell was selected before** and then the `tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` will be called for the **newly selected cell**.

```swift
    class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = false
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("This will be called for each cell tap")
    }
```