# Swift Nesting UITableView in UIScrollView

Tags: uitableview, swift, uiscrollview

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21677268/uitableview-inside-uiscrollview-not-receiving-first-tap-after-scrollling) and one of the answers referring to this [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) embedding a UITableView in a UIScroll view isn't a very reliable option, however I am looking for a specific type of functionality in that I have a table list of data to my left and a menu to my right (digram below).  I would like to be able to scroll to my menu while leaving an edge of the table data for view (somewhat like the "peeking" section of [this tuorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/76436/use-uiscrollview-scroll-zoom-content-swift))

I am able to do this using the tutorial listed above and nesting a subview:

```
let page = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TableData") as! UIViewController
scrollView.addSubview(page.view)
```

However, and as expected by the warnings from apple, this causes some pretty undesirable behavior when I attempt to scroll the table.  So, my question is, how else would I implement this type of menu/list?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you try giving your UITableView a constant NSLayoutConstraint for it's height?

So pin the tableView to the top, trailing, and leading edges of the UIScrollView.

Then give it a constant height (height of cell * number of cells)