# Selecting first row in UITableViewController in Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview

I am trying to select the first row in the UITableViewController once it appears (through a segue).

I am using the following code which I inherited from my previous Objective C project:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let customCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! IGANavlistTableCustomViewCell

        // Code that sets the custom view cell

        // Then...
        // Selecting the first row by default
        if(indexPath.row == 0)
        {
            let rowToSelect:NSIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)

            tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(rowToSelect, animated: true, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.None)

            tableView.delegate?.tableView!(tableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath: rowToSelect)
        }

        return customCell;
    }
```

I receive the following error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[IGANavlistTableVC tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x79e21040'
```

I would appreciate if someone could help.

Thank you!

EDIT:

This is my didDeselectRowAtIndexPath method:

```
var navaidSelected = [String]()
var listOfNavPoints = [[String]]()

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
    {
        // The selected object of the Array with all navaids data (i.e., the selected navaid) is converted to a string
        self.navaidSelected = self.listOfNavPoints[indexPath.row]
    }
```

Comment: Are you using a storyboard? Is everything hooked up correctly?

Comment: The error points to didSelectRowAtIndexPath. Can you show the code for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot implement `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)` method.

And you needn't to use `delegate` when call `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`:

```
if(indexPath.row == 0)
        {
            let rowToSelect:NSIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)

            tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(rowToSelect, animated: true, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.None)

           self.tableView(tableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath: rowToSelect)
        }
```

**=== EDITED ===**

Change your `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` to `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, I did not include it in the original message. Corrected. Also, having it your way gives me the following error: "Cannot call value of non-function type 'UITableView'".

Comment: Thank you. Changed. No compilation error, but still the runtime error. Interesting that if I select the second row and then the first row and select it, no error occurs.

Comment: The excited question about this here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2106292/uitableview-didselectrowatindexpath-not-being-called-on-first-tap

Comment: Thank you so much! I thought I was going crazy. Three days of trying to find the error because of two extra letters! Appreciate your help!