# How to type the next part of method name show in autocomplete?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, autocomplete

As all we know, the method name of Swift or Objective C is divided into multiple parts for each corresponding parameter.

When we call the method, XCode will hint the autocompletion. Example, the `UITableViewDelegate` protocol, when we type `tableV...` it will hint me a lot of methods, then we use the Up/Down arrow key to select which method we want. But, use the arrow key is very time consumed. And it also cause risk. Example, more than 1000 people has chosen the method `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)` instead of `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)`, because it's the first hint. See the funny question about this problem [here - Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2106292/uitableview-didselectrowatindexpath-not-being-called-on-first-tap).

Is there a way to type the next part of method name to the autocompletion hint the result with more exact? Example, when I type `tableView` then use another key (Tab key, or something like this) and then continue type `didselec....`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to bring up different result set besides that the xCode has to offer for you when you type BUT I could recommend you a different result set :)

Try using this plugin using Alcatraz:

https://github.com/FuzzyAutocomplete/FuzzyAutocompletePlugin

It uses a different algorithm. I have tried it and it's way better.

Sometimes these plugins give you troubles: xCode crashes. Mostly when updating xCode and old plugin not cooping with it.