# prepareForSegue Method dosn't work when setting editing to yes

Tags: ios, uitableview, uistoryboardsegue

I have a normal TableView with seven Sections.
Otherwise I have a prepareForSegue method. Everything runs fine. But when I am setting the edit Mode in viewDidLoad

```
[self.tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];
```

My prepareForSegue method doesn't work anymore.

For editing i have implement these methods

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

Hope you can help me out. Thanks.

Comment: how you are navigating to other view from tableView? programmatically?  is didSelectRowAtIndexPath is calling in editing mode?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When editing, by default users are not allowed to select a table view cell. I believe the segue is only triggered when users select a table view cell, in which it calls the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

You can change this behaviour by setting `allowsSelectionDuringEditing` property of the table view:

```
self.tableView.allowsSelectionDuringEditing = YES;
```

Similar question here:

[When editing, `UITableView` does not call didSelectRowAtIndexPath ??](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047538/enable-editing-does-not-call-didselectrowatindexpath)