# didSelectRowAtIndexPath not get called

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, didselectrowatindexpath

I have a UITableView inside a UIViewController like so:

.h

```
@interface OutageListViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource> {
   IBOutlet UITableView *outageTable;
```

.m

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   NSLog(@"Selected");
}
```

I have customized table cell:

//EDIT
I have fire UILabel side by side on my customized view, as well as a background spreading the entire area. But after resizing/removing the background image and label I putted on the customized cell, "didSelectRowAtIndexPath" is still not being called. 
//END EDIT

```
@interface AbstractSummaryListViewCell : UITableViewCell {...}
```

and

```
@interface FiveColumnSummaryCell : AbstractSummaryListViewCell {...}
```

This UIView is inside another UIView:

```
@interface CustomTabBarController : UIViewController {
   OutageListViewController *outageListViewController;
```

And my AppDelegate add this to the window:

```
[window addSubview:[customTabBarController view]];
```

Now I'm trying to determine which cell get clicked and didSelectRowAtIndexPath doesn't get called, I have dataSource and delegate connect from the UITableView to File's Owner, in fact the data populates correctly as my "cellForRowAtIndexPath" specifies, any ideas how can I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: When you touch the cell, does it turn blue for a second?

Comment: Alex, sorry for missing this information from my original post. No, it doesn't turn blue when I touch it. I can scroll up and down and data is showing correctly though.

Comment: Try removing one of the subviews so there's a "hole" and tap the cell there, let us know what happens, we need to narrow down the problem in order to fix it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [-didSelectRowAtIndexPath: not being called](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255927/didselectrowatindexpath-not-being-called)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it: forgot to check **User Interaction Enabled** in my customized cell xib. What a fool!

Answer (score 3):

Are the following properties of UITableView all `YES`?

- allowsSelection
- allowsSelectionDuringEditing

`Edit`: 
I think Paul is right. The delegate property has some problem. You can check the delegate property of tableView inside -(void)viewDidLoad. As you said, they should be connected to FileOwner in xib. So the following codes won't obtain nil.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];

   // They should not be nil.
   NSLog(@"delegate:%@ dataSource:%@", self.tableView.delegate, self.tableView.dataSource);
}
```

Comment: allowSelection is default to YES and allows SelectionDurningEditing is default to NO, since I don't need editing feature, I kept them that way. Even with a outageTable.allowSelection = YES, I still don't see the cell turns blue when I touch it.

Comment: I has edited my answer, you might need to check the properties about tableView.

Comment: I added the NSLog to my `OutageListViewController`'s `viewDidLoad` and I got **delegate:<OutageListViewController: 0x5a8f620> dataSource:<OutageListViewController: 0x5a8f620>** as input.


However I have to do `outageTable.delegate` and `outageTable.dataSource`, if I add `self`, there's an error telling me **Property 'outageTable' not found on object of type 'OutageListViewController *'**, any ideas?

(In .h, I have `IBOutlet UITableView *outageTable`, but I don't have `@property` and `@synthesize` for it.)

Comment: Well, is the 0x5a8f620 the same as `self`, which is responsible for the method `-(void)tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` ? The original problem seems like that method doesn't fire. As for me, I will add `@property` and `@synthesize` for it. I remember an Apple official document suggests add them under iOS.

Comment: Maybe you can find something useful in this `Table View Programming Guire`, which provides some sample codes about table view. http://goo.gl/2xvnO.

Comment: I nslog `self` and it's **<OutageListViewController: 0x5a8f620>** as well, so I think the connection from UITableView to File's owner should be fine, right?

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that the view controller has not been connected to the `delegate` property of the `outageTable` anywhere.

Comment: `outageTable`'s `delegate` is connect to File's Owner, which is a `UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>`, is that what you're referring to? Thanks.

Comment: @Derek Yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: So I verified the connection in IB, as well as the NSLog method TORO mentioned below, and it seems the connection is working fine, any ideas what the problem might be? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a quick test... Remove the "big" label and see if the didSelectRowAtIndexPath is called.

Comment: I tested this right after I post the question, no after removing the background image and label I putted on the customized cell, "didSelectRowAtIndexPath" is still not being called.