# UITableView didSelectRowAt indexPath not called in custom cell

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I create new ViewController and drag new UITableView it works, but in my previous two ViewControllers cannot work.

All the following I already done:

1. UITableViewDelegate  .delegate=self
2. UITableViewDataSource  .datasource=self
3. Swift3 and is didSelectRowAt not didDeselectRowAt
4. .setEditing(true, animated: true)
5. .allowsSelection = true
6. .allowsSelectionDuringEditing = true
7. SingelSelection

and all my data can be load into tableview, only thing is cannot select rows, in MainViewController actually I only have one table view, another one is used for testing.

[image]
-This is one of the viewcontroller my tableview cannot select row but can load data, here I only have one tableview, but to test I create a new table view

[image]
-This is the second viewcontroller cannot select row

#### This is my MainViewController

```
extension MainViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return 10
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if tableView == self.tableview_restaurants {

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! RestaurantsCell

            cell.label_name.text = "OMG Restaurant # \(String(indexPath.row))"

            return cell
        }
        else if tableView == self.tableview_test {

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! TableviewtestCell

            cell.label_test.text = String(indexPath.row)

            return cell
        }
        else {
            let cell = UITableViewCell()

            return cell
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        //tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        if tableView == self.tableview_restaurants {

        }
        else if tableView == self.tableview_test {
            print("select this row")
            print(indexPath)
        }
    }
}
```

#### This is my FilterViewController

```
extension SearchFilterViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        var numberofrowsinsecion:Int = 0

        if (tableView == self.tableview_quickfilters) {

            numberofrowsinsecion = json_quickfilters["filters"].arrayValue.count
            //print(numberofrowsinsecion)
        }

        else if (tableView == self.tableview_cuisinetype) {
            numberofrowsinsecion = json_cuisinetype["cuisine_types"].arrayValue.count
            //print(numberofrowsinsecion)
        }

        return numberofrowsinsecion
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if (tableView == self.tableview_quickfilters) {

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! QuickFiltersCell

            let filter = json_quickfilters["filters"].arrayValue

            if let filter_name = cell.label_quickfiltersname {

                filter_name.text = filter[indexPath.row]["name"].stringValue
                filter_name.font = Common.Config.FontSize.XL_L
            }
            return cell
        }

        else if (tableView == self.tableview_cuisinetype) {

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! CuisineTypeCell

            let cuisinetype = json_cuisinetype["cuisine_types"].arrayValue

            if let cuisinetype_name = cell.label_cuisinetypename {

                cuisinetype_name.text = cuisinetype[indexPath.row]["name"].stringValue
                cuisinetype_name.font = Common.Config.FontSize.XL_L
            }
            return cell
        }

        else {
            let cell = UITableViewCell()
            return cell
        }

    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if (tableView == self.tableview_quickfilters) {

            print(indexPath)

            //let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! QuickFiltersCell

        } else if (tableView == self.tableview_cuisinetype) {

            print(indexPath)

            //let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! CuisineTypeCell

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: How are you presenting the second table view?  Is the view containing it allowing user interaction?

Comment: func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       //  if condition for check table and give its return value
        

    }

Comment: In which controller, Didselect method not working ?

Comment: I delete one table and left one but still doesn't work, i add self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true also cannot. I can select the row in tableview and that row will show grey when i tap, but doest call didSelectRowAt indexPath

Comment: Both controllers does't work

Comment: Ok, Will you send me project So I can Understand it, If you dont mind ? @YangXu

Comment: @Jecky okay can , but how to send you

Comment: Send it on modijecky@gmail.com. I will check it and reply to you

Comment: @YangXu Ok, I got it will reply you as soon as possible

Comment: you can add UITapGesturerecognizer in viewcontroller?

Comment: does the table view scroll?

Comment: post the code for customCell . What you have write there? Why both of the cell's identifier is same?

Comment: yes can, find the problem, dismiss keyboard add gesture is the problem

Comment: Maybe you forgot to delegate your viewController for UITableViewDataSource and  UITableViewDelegate

Answer (score 4):

You most likely have added a tap gesture somewhere that cancels the cell taps. Check the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9248827/1286291