# UITableView didSelectRowAt does not register

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a custom `UITableView` in a `ViewController`. My custom table has custom `UITableViewCells`. This is the code inside my `ViewController`:

`ViewDidLoad`:

```
        self.firstListTable.dataSource = self
        self.firstListTable.delegate = self
        self.firstListTable.register(UINib(nibName: "firstQueueCell", bundle: Bundle.main), forCellReuseIdentifier: "firstCell")

        self.searchListTable.dataSource = self
        self.searchListTable.delegate = self
        self.searchListTable.allowsSelection = true
        self.searchListTable.register(UINib(nibName: "SearchCell", bundle: Bundle.main), forCellReuseIdentifier: "SearchCell")
        self.searchListTable.separatorStyle = .none
```

`UITableViewFunctions`:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didHighlightRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if tableView == self.searchListTable {
        print("hello") 
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){
   print("hello")
}
```

`didHighlightRowAt` works but `didSelectRowAt` does not.

I tried this: 
[didSelectRowAtIndexPath: not being called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8952688/didselectrowatindexpath-not-being-called/9248827#9248827)

What other causes could there be?

Thanks!

Comment: looks like there is no error in your code, can you post all the code about it let us have a look if is other place goes wrong?

Comment: @user82395214, checked your code. Nothing wrong with it. Both of them are responding. Can you change `print` statement for `didSelectRowAt` method from `print("hello")` to something different and check it again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want `didHighlightRowAt` and `didSelectRowAt` both response, you can overwrite your method `didHighlightRowAt` like this :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didHighlightRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
if tableView == self.searchListTable {
    print("hello") 

    // this is my OC code ,change it to your swift code 
    [tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:IndexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];

    }
}
```

You can understand this as `didHighlightRowAt` method and `didSelectRowAt` method have conflicts, if you want both method response, you must make some special treatment.

Comment: Oh sorry, no I'm trying to say that my `didHighlight` works, but `didSelect` doesn't. I don't want the user to have to hold a cell to interact with it.

Comment: i know what you want, but if overwrite the both method like your code, `didSelectRowAt` is very hard to response. user must click very much time to call `didSelectRowAt`.

Comment: can you tell me the real effort you want in `didHighlightRowAt`? i suggest you put the code for your effort in `didSelectRowAt` method.