# didSelectRowAtIndexPath really doesn't work

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

The didSelectRowAtIndexPath not working.
Have I configured the 2 delegates. Everything is linked (tableview, tableviewcell).
Already deleted and did it again.
I searched for everything here and nothing worked.
I think this was one of the best [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255927/didselectrowatindexpath-not-being-called), still to no avail.

My last hope is that it is, I'm opening my ViewController, where has this tableview, for modal. But it would be VERY wrong the problem.

Other than that, I need some help

Somo codes .H

```
@interface simulator : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UIScrollViewDelegate>
{
   NSArray                                          *array_products;
}
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary          *plist_products;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITableView  *table_menu_left;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString              *file_plist;

@end
```

Some codes .M

```
#import "cel_products.h"

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   NSString *path_root      = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
   NSString *full_path      = [path_root stringByAppendingPathComponent:self.file_plist];
   self.plist_products      = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:full_path];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"id_cell_products";
   UITableViewCell *cell           = [self.table_menu_left dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

   array_products                  = [self.plist_produtcs allKeys];
   if (cell == nil)
   {
       NSArray *topLevelObjects    = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"cel_products" owner:self options:nil];

       for(id currentObject in topLevelObjects)
       {
           if([currentObject isKindOfClass:[cel_products class]])
           {
               cell = (cel_products *)currentObject;
               break;
           }
       }
   }
   cell.textLabel.text       = [array_products objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   return cell;
}

// numberofrowsinsection - OK
// numberofsectionintableviw - OK

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   NSLog(@"Hein?????");
   // Nothing..........
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I humbly thousand apologies to all!
I inadvertently clicked Attributes Inspector> Selection: **NO SELECTION**

So I do not find anything in the code.

Again, I apologize to everyone, but if someone, are having this problem, this is one more step to be verified. " Change to Attributes Inspector> Selection: **SINGLE SELECTION or MULTIPLE SELECTION** ( is up to you )

Thanks all for the answers and help

Comment: please answer you own question! Like this questions are kept open and popping up in unanswered.

Answer (score 1):

Did you set a break at `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`? Try and see if it breaks successfully there.

Expanding on [rokjark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/653513/rokjarc)'s answer you have to manually set the delegate and data source to the file in question.

Your header file `simulator.h` simply declares it as **A** delegate/data source for **SOME** UITableView.

You still need to point `table_menu_left` to use `simulator.h` as **THE** delegate file to handle all of it's callbacks.

Set:

```
self.table_menu_left.delegate = self;
self.table_menu_left.datasource = self;
```

And again set a break in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and see if it gets called.

Comment: i set a brak, and does not enter on this method. All delegates are seted and all IB conector are seted. I have 4 apps using same scheme of this tableview code, all works perfect, 1 of them use 2 tableviews on the same code, work perfect. Only difference on this project, is that open a view as modal. Only that is different. Pretty wired!!!

Comment: So you're opening the view through a modal segue?

Did you set the delegate (or delegates if you have multiple `UITableViews`) properly in the `prepareForSegue` in the view you're segueing from?

Comment: i do no use historyboard... but i answer with the solution ;)