# didSelectRowAtIndexPath is not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, delegates

In my app I want to catch reactions from my UITableView but I do not why it doesn't work:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 NSLog(@"touched!");
}
```

I defined the delegate

```
@interface TableViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate>
```

I ticked the "user interaction enable" from the nib file showed the delegate to the files owner.

I also write `tableView.delegate = self;` to the viewDidLoad. What am I missing?

Comment: im having the same problem and no one was able to help me either. no idea what is causing this issue but its extremely annoying

Comment: check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255927/didselectrowatindexpath-not-being-called

Comment: What about cells? Are you using something that prevents delegate to fire?

Comment: @Flex_Addicted I am planning to but not yet. My table view is just empty.

Comment: If it's empty then no cells can receive the taps..because there are no cells. Populate the table with something and it should work.

Comment: The problem could be that. Try to use a dummy data source and see what happens...

Comment: Expanding on @Flex_Addicted's comment, post your `cellForRowAtIndex` method.

Comment: Not just could be, the problem is definitely that.  How can a row be selected when there are zero rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `datasource` for your table. Put some data in the table n then see if the delegate is called. If it still doesn't then, usually the problem with delegate not getting called is that its not getting set properly.! so, double check your code..:)

Answer (score 3):

Try making the delegates connection in the IB. and check that you declare this:UITableViewDataSource

along with `UITableViewDelegate`.

Answer (score 2):

Be sure you have the `UITableViewDataSource` delegate in your header as well.

Comment: I did it but nothing changed:/

Comment: link the datasource in Interfacebuilder too. Also, make sure there's something in your array that's filling the table, or else it won't recognize/populate the table to be selected in the frist place