# didSelectRowAtIndexPath does not trigger in ViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

So, I've added a `UITableViewController` and `UITableViewCell` into a `UIViewController` and while the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` delegate method works, `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` does not. Does anyone have any ideas?

- EDIT 2: The delegate for the `UITableView` is set to the `UIViewController`.
- EDIT 3: I found the answer to my issue on another Stack question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255927/didselectrowatindexpath-not-being-called). Basically I had a `UITap...` on my `[self view]` that was blocking the `didSelectRow...`. I have no idea why the tap blocks the delegate method and I also have no idea how to get both the tap and the table working together simultaneously.
- EDIT: The part that bugs me is that I've gotten this exact setup working on an earlier app. So that means I've missed a step somewhere along the way. The thing is, I've combed over all the steps and have compared previous app vs current app and I really have no idea what I missed.

I've added logging to both delegate methods and while one outputs, the other does not.

ViewController.h

```
#import "...TableViewCell.h"
...
    UITableViewDataSource,
    UITableViewDelegate
...
```

ViewController.m

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"cellForRowAtIndexPath");
    ...
    return Cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"didSelectRowAtIndexPath");
}
```

...TableViewCell.h (contents not important)

...TableViewCell.m (contents not important)

Comment: Since the `cellForRow...` method is called we know the table's `dataSource` is set. Did you also set the table's `delegate` property? Without setting that the `didSelectRow...` method won't be called.

Comment: Hi rmaddy, yes, the `UITableView` delegate property is set to the `UIViewController`.
*Edit: I accidentally said `UITableViewController` but I meant to say `UIViewController`.

Comment: Check very carefully that you spelled it correctly, with proper capitalization.

Comment: Hi Hot Licks, I just double checked (can never be too sure) and it's spelled exactly right, let me copy/paste here: `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer on [another StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255927/didselectrowatindexpath-not-being-called).

I had a `UITapGestureRecognizer` added to `[self view]` which I commented out, and then the delegate method worked.

Can anyone please tell me why this worked and also how I can get the `UITapGestureRecognizer` working on the same screen as the `UITableView`?

```
// Hide keyboard when user taps outside of it
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer =
    [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                            action:@selector(hideKeyboardOnTap)];
//[[self view] addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
```

- EDIT: Corrected typo of `UITapeGestureRecognizer` to `UITapGestureRecognizer`

Comment: Uh, I think that's "UITapGestureRecognizer".  (And it is a bit mysterious.  Best thing, if possible, is to add the recognizer to a subview that is not the one where you want to pick up touches in other ways.)

Answer (score 1):

have you set the delegate of the `tableView`?

`myTableView.delegate = self;`

EDIT: My bad, did not read that cell for row is being called.

You say that you have used a custom `tableViewController`. If you have overridden the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method, it might be important to call `[super didSelectRowAtIndexPath:]` in the `tableViewController`

EDIT 2: One more thing. I do not know the reason for this, but I faced the same issue some time back in a `viewController`. I resolved it by adding an empty implementation of `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath`in the same `viewController`. Try adding it to your table's `delegate` controller.

Comment: Not your bad. One is from the `dataSource` and the other is from the `delegate`.

Answer (score 0):

To answer to the question "how I can get the UITapGestureRecognizer working on the same screen as the UITableView";

You should "inform" your GestureRecognizer that other Recognizer can handle the same gesture:

You do that by implementing the method of `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`

> -(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer

This is a small exemple...

```
@interface MyController : UIViewController<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>  
{ 
}  
@end  


-(void)viewDidLoad  
{  
    UITapGestureRecognizer *gr = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self  action:@selector(actionOnTapGesture:)];  
    [gr setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];  
    [gr setDelegate:self];  
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:gr];    
}  

-(BOOL) gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *) gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *) otherGestureRecognizer  
{  
    return YES;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check in the interface builder if the property selection is set to 'No selection'.
Change it to 'Single selection' or other option according to your needs.

This might be the reason why didSelect is not getting triggered.