# Contact App - Search and apply Selection Style

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

[Edited Post]

For practicing, I developing a contact app without any backend. I followed only one NSMutableArray for maintaining contacts which is displayed in a UITableView.

Objective;

- Like to search a contact (Ex: Dad), user given a name in a textfield and touch up a button
- In the button action,  check if Dad contain in the Mutable array which one i followed.

  - If present, then it definitely present in the tableView as a row. So i want to put selectionStyle for that row.
  - If search text changes means (Ex: Mom), then revert previous selectionStyle and apply to the row(Mom).
  - If not present, label notify "Not Present" as text. (Done!).

**IBAction:**

```
-(IBAction)actionSearchNameInTable:(id)sender{
if([myContactsArray containsObject:txtForContactName.text]){
myTable.tag=5;
NSInteger tempIndex=[myContactsArray indexOfObject:txtForContactName.text];    
NSIndexPath *tempIndexPath=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:tempIndex inSection:0];   
[self tableView:myTable didSelectRowAtIndexPath:tempIndexPath]; //broke here
NSLog(@"Call Passed!"); 
}
}
```

**didSelectRowAtIndexPath:**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath  *)indexPath{
if(myTable.tag==5){
NSLog(@"called done!");
//Here i like to select that row and apply selectionStyle or favorite background color for that cell, idea?.
myTable.tag=0;
}
```

These are all just other part of my application. I sured that, Delegate and Datasource are connected properly.

Comment: You are calling "didDeselectRowAtIndexPath" and not "didSelectRowAtIndexPath".
And I think you have not implemented "didDeselectRowAtIndexPath" in your class so thats the reason of crash.

Comment: Where you have implemented "didDeselectRowAtIndexPath" method ?

Comment: Sorry to all and your time.Silly Mistake happened. @PoojaM.Bohora caught that problem first. And i like to share this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255927/didselectrowatindexpath-not-being-called)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
-(IBAction)actionSearchNameInTable:(id)sender{
if([myContactsArray containsObject:txtForContactName.text]){
myTable.tag=5;
NSInteger tempIndex=[myContactsArray indexOfObject:txtForContactName.text];
NSLog(@"TEmp index:%i",tempIndex);
NSIndexPath *tempIndexPath=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:tempIndex inSection:0];
NSLog(@"Temp IP:%@",tempIndexPath);
[self tableView:myTable didSelectRowAtIndexPath]; //broke here
NSLog(@"Call Passed!"); 
}
}
```

And for custom selection background do this in your **cellForRowAtIndexPath**.

```
UIView *customColorView = [[UIView alloc] init];
customColorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:180/255.0
                                                  green:138/255.0
                                                   blue:171/255.0
                                                  alpha:0.5];
cell.selectedBackgroundView =  customColorView;
```

Hope this helps.. :)

**EDIT:**

`didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is a delegate. It only get called when user interaction happens. I face a same problem some days ago. I did it in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. For selecting a row do this:

```
if ([[myContactsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:txtForContactName.text]) {
        [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
}
```

Comment: why i use `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and why i cant achieve in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: Your code change background when i select row manually. But, i want to select a row which is present in `txtForContactName.text`.

Comment: Use of undeclared 'dataSource'. happened.

Comment: dataSource is the array from where I am getting the cell data.

Comment: From where you are getting the data. If you can't understand share cellForRowAtIndexPath code.

Comment: - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{    
    ....dequeue....
    myTableCell.textLabel.text=[myContactsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    myTableCell.imageView.image=[myContactsPhotosArray objectAtIndex:0];
}
return myTableCell;
}

Comment: Your code worked but want reloadData. Then only selectionStyle visibled. Now, where do i put reloadData.

Comment: I could not understand what you are asking. :(

Comment: I have one separate button action `Reload` for just reloadData of tableView. Your code gives result only after put `Reload` action. ie. result only comes if we reloadData of the tableView.

Comment: Most possible reason is that while populating the table view for the first time txtForContactName.text may be nil or there is no match in myContactsArray.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` and not `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

And I think you have not implemented `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` in your class so thats the reason of crash.

and for your another question:

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(cell.tag==100)
    {
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor=[UIColor grayColor];

    }
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UITableViewCell *cell=[tblviw cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.tag=100;
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor=[UIColor grayColor];
}
```

Comment: Yes, you right. Silly mistake happened. can you answer me for another help.

Comment: I'll accept your answer. But, please help me for 2nd question which asked in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method in my post.

Comment: what is second question?

Comment: pls See my post. i comment the question in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: apply background color in last cell of the tableViewCell. But i want to apply color or selectionStyle for which i search in the `actionSearchNameInTable` method.

Comment: Like @Rashad code, your code also wants reloadData. which is best place to put reloadData.

Comment: @UdanPirappu: My code do not require reload data. I written willDisplayCell incase we scroll up or down then changes done in didselectrow atindex path will not get revert.

Comment: But, Pooja due to `contentView.backgroundColor` the selection (Dad) applied permanently. Is there any other to remove it after another search action? And, i got one way of result from Rashad answer.

Comment: You may reset it in didDeSelectRowAtIndexPath method.

Comment: How to reset the backgroundColor? And please see my answer. It got one way of result.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to see my edited answer...

```
-(IBAction)actionSearchNameInTable:(id)sender{
    if([myContactsArray containsObject:txtForContactName.text]){
    myTable.tag=5;
    NSInteger tempIndex=[myContactsArray indexOfObject:txtForContactName.text];
    NSLog(@"TEmp index:%i",tempIndex);
    NSIndexPath *tempIndexPath=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:tempIndex inSection:0];
    NSLog(@"Temp IP:%@",tempIndexPath);
    [self tableView:myTable didSelectRowAtIndexPath:tempIndexPath]; //Change here......
    NSLog(@"Call Passed!"); 
}
}
```

Comment: @dharmnir: As per title of the question he want to call "didSelectRowAtIndexPath" and not "didDeSelectRowAtIndexPath"

Comment: @dharmnir: There is no need to implement "didDeSelectRowAtIndexPath" if he don't want to call that method.Instead he just want to correct the method call of "didSelectRowAtIndexPath" .

Comment: Yes i know. But i didn't get him.

Answer (score 0):

Action for searching that if given text is present or not:

```
-(IBAction)actionSearchNameInTable:(id)sender{
 [txtForContactName resignFirstResponder];
if([myContactsArray containsObject:txtForContactName.text]){
    myTable.tag=5;
    [myTable reloadData];
}
}
```

In cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
//Better delegate to apply selection style
//Code after dequeue...
myTableCell.textLabel.text=[myContactsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
myTableCell.imageView.image=[myContactsPhotosArray objectAtIndex:0];
{
myTableCell.textLabel.text=[myContactsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
myTableCell.imageView.image=[myContactsPhotosArray objectAtIndex:0];
if(myTable.tag==5){
NSLog(@"Ready to apply selectionStyle");
if ([[myContactsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:txtForContactName.text]) {
[myTable selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
myTable.tag=0;           
}
}
return myTableCell;
}
```