# Segue is not working for tableview cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have the following code having capability such that, once I tap on the table cell it will go to another view controller where it has its description. I am trying to do it programmatically.

This is my code that controls the segue part, **which is not getting called**:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
    DetailViewController *detailVC = (DetailViewController*)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"detailViewController"];
    detailVC.navigationItem.title = self.ourNumberOfQuotes[indexPath];
    detailVC.indexRow =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",indexPath];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailVC animated:YES];

}
```

Why is this not getting called?

This is my .h file code

```
@interface QuoteTableViewController : UITableViewController <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate> {
    int i;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *mainMenu;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *homeworkButton;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *uploadButton;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *arrayOfOurQuotes;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *ourNumberOfQuotes;
```

Comment: Look for nil values in your code. Since in Obj-C, calls to nil are handled. Do you have a `self.navigationController`? Is detailVC actually being created as well or not?

Comment: Are you using a navigation controller? It's probably a view controller and that's why it doesn't work. Try `[seld presentViewController:]`

Comment: There is a navigationController before my tableViewController. But i do i know if detailVC is being created?

Comment: Add breakpoint at line where you're pushing view controller and after stop, type lldb command "po detailVC"

Comment: As @iosDev82 says, do some debugging and check every line in that function runs and that the values are not nil for your storyboard and VC and navigationController.

Comment: @DineshSekar, change the line to [self presentViewController:]

Comment: @RoryMcKinnel how would i check that those thing you stated are not nil?

Comment: @WMios isn't it like the same line of code i have? Or are you trying to say something else?

Comment: Change `[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailVC animated:YES];` to `[self pushViewController:detailVC animated:YES];`

Comment: What happens when you do that?

Comment: Also it's supposed to be     [self presentViewController:detailVC animated:YES];

Comment: nothing. It is the same thing

Comment: Well it's supposed to be presentViewController not pushViewController

Comment: @DineshSekar Click on the left of the code line and you should see a break point added. When you run the code will stop on that line. Step over each line using the step over icon. Looks like a horizontal bar with a right angled arrow on top. Hover your mouse over the variable of interest and it will show you its value. You can also type `print <insert variable name>` in the console and it will print the value out. Or add lots of NSLog statements. Really you should know this and have done this before posting.

Comment: But the problem is that the void is not running. I can't tap on any of the cells. So even is i add breakpoints it is to of no use

Comment: So then you're showing us the wrong piece of code...

Comment: You should have posted the `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method

Comment: i do have my array shown up there.

Comment: Is the correct text appearing on each cell?

Comment: yes it is. Only the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is not running

Comment: possible duplicate of [-didSelectRowAtIndexPath: not being called](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255927/didselectrowatindexpath-not-being-called)

Comment: If your code doesn't enter the didDelectRowAtIndexPath method, then you probably haven't set your tableView's delegate.

Comment: You have to implement UITableViewDelegate, that's like TableView 101...

Comment: And you need [self.tableView setDelegate:self];

[self.tableView setDataSource:self];

Comment: Oh so you did set the delegate and datasource?

Comment: yes i did set/implement it

Comment: I would check out the previous questions that ask this same thing and find what your missing.

Comment: Include your .h file code too

Comment: i gave a link to download my whole project in the post

Comment: Yeah I'm not downloading your project. I'd much rather you include the relevant code for your question.

Comment: thanks for your help and sorry for the inconvenience. I just realised my mistake. I had a tap gesture on the view itself.

Comment: Ok, I've included an answer here with the information from the link I had posted above which answers your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [-didSelectRowAtIndexPath: not being called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255927/didselectrowatindexpath-not-being-called):

> I have encountered two things in this situations.
>
> You may have forgot to implement UITableViewDelegate protocol, or
>   there's no delegation outlet between your class and your table view.
>
> You might have a UIView inside your row that is a first responder and
>   takes your clicks away. Say a UIButton or something similar.

You should check to make sure you have implemented the UITableViewDelegate protocol and you need to make sure that you are clicking the cell and not a view or gesture recognizer that is in front of it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you switching to a different storyboard that your current viewController is already using? If it's the same, please change the code within your method (see below) - This line here UIStoryboard... isn't needed.

```
    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
```

isn't needed. You can call self.storyboard

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

   DetailViewController *detailVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"detailViewController"];
   detailVC.navigationItem.title = self.ourNumberOfQuotes[indexPath];
   detailVC.indexRow =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",indexPath];

   [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailVC animated:YES];
    }
```

Providing the detailVC has been set with the storyboard identifier @"detailViewController" of course.

Answer (score 0):

Okay here is the problem, when I commented out your gesture codes from your viewDidLoad method, the delegate method, `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` gets called.

Here is what I figured, either the swipe gesture works and cell selection doesn't or if you remove the gesture part, the selection work and didSelectRowAtIndexPath gets called. As I never worked with gesture, I am not sure how to make both actions work together.

Hope this helps a little.

Comment: the problem is that i cannot even go to the DetailViewCotroller. So what is the purpose of putting a breakpoint at the `-viewDidLoad` method when it doesn't even load

Comment: I gave you step by step debugging points. You would try to put breakpoint in DetailViewController if your code would have passed the first 2 steps.

Comment: This is all correct here, you maybe forgot to include the <UITableViewDelegate> reference in your .h

Comment: I edited my response based on the updated question and looking into the sample code.