# didSelectRowAtIndexPath is not work

Tags: swift, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

the cell is very simple, just a textLabel. i want to tap the cell and  then print some words. this is a test . but the didSelectRowAtIndexPath is not work. Please tell me why, thank you !

```
import UIKit
import SnapKit

class ListTableViewController : UITableViewController{
    var itemData: ListTableModel!
    var header: UIView!
    override init(style: UITableViewStyle){
        super.init(style: style)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        itemData = ListTableModel()
        self.tableView.dataSource = self
        self.tableView.delegate = self


    }


    ....


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("mCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.userInteractionEnabled = false
        let listCell = cell as! ListTableViewCell
        if let item = itemData.getItemData(indexPath.row) {
            listCell.textLabel!.text = item.valueForKey("title") as? String
        }

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        print("indexPathS")
    }

}
```

Comment: Looks duplicate. Refer this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12855662/3051458

Comment: class ListTableViewController : UITableViewController , UITableViewDelegate{...}   it will show error: Redundant conformance of "ListTableViewController" to protocol "UITableViewDelegate".

Answer (score 2):

Please check if `self.tableView.allowsSelection = NO` is not written anywhere. And in the storyboard, check if `single selection` is checked under Selection tab.

Comment: check in XIB file then ?

Comment: there is no "self.tableView.allowsSelection = NO"  in all files

Comment: are you overriding the touch gestures in any way in your custom cell class?

Comment: no. the cell is very simple:

import UIKit

class ListTableViewCell: UITableViewCell{
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    override init(style:UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?){
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier)
    }
    
}

Answer (score 0):

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
        let text:NSString = myArray .objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! NSString
        delegate?.myMethod(text as String)
        self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)

    }
```

you can try this.