# not calling didSelectRowAtIndexPath method in Tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I have embedded **UITabbar** in **UIViewController** and then I put some UITabbarItems in my **UITabbar**. I also created another **UIViewController** with **UITableView** embedded in it.

I have linked one of the **UITabbarItem** with this newly created **UIViewController**(with UITableView in it).

When I run the program and tap on that **UITabbarItem** it shows a table view but when I select any row of table, the data displaying in **UITableView** disappears.
I then debug the code and found that `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`  method didn't call.

I searched on the internet and find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255927/didselectrowatindexpath-not-being-called) but cannot understand it well.
I tried by implementing both types of **tableViews** (`UITableViewController`,`UIViewController` with `UITableView` in it) but still same problem.
I am stuck here. Anyone please help me. How to get resolve this issue.
I will be very Thankful to you.
Here is my swift code

```
import UIKit

class DashboardViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    var selectedIndexPathForCheckMark:NSIndexPath?

        var items: [String] = ["We", "Heart", "Swift"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "MyCell")
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MyCell")!UITableViewCell

        cell.textLabel?.text = self.items[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.row)!")

        selectedIndexPathForCheckMark = indexPath
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

here are its snapshots

[image]
[image]
Second `UITabbarItem` from right implements `UITableView`

Comment: Why would the screen content change if the selection event, as you are saying, is not processed ?

Comment: are you using any tap gesture recognize here .....

Comment: you have set the tableview tableView.delegate = self
tableView.dataSource = self ...?

Comment: remember that I am not using **TabbarController**

Comment: -Kishore Kumar No i am not using tap gesture

Comment: -Sohil I have set the delegate and datasource form storyboard

Comment: -A-Live I don't know why the screen content change on selection event.

Comment: **Tableview** runs fine without using **Tabbar**

Comment: @user:2116098 have you any idea about this problem

Answer (score 0):

Follow Steps:
1. Take A view controller and add tableview.
2. set outlet with MytabelView
3. set Datasource and delegate of tableview to ViewController
4. and put the following code in ViewController class
5. Take a custom tableview cell with name MyCell having cell identifier "MyCellid"
6. Create swift file with name MyCell, make it subclass of UITableViewCell
7. Choose custom cell and assign it class to MyCell.

I think Its done

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{

@IBOutlet weak var MytableView: UITableView!
 var items: [String] = ["We", "Heart", "Swift"]
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.MytableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "MyCellid")
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.MytableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MyCellid")! as UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel?.text = self.items[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return items.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.row)!")

}
}
```

Comment: Dear -Avinash Jadhav I already have set it from storyboard. I also tried it from code as you did but still not resolved.

Comment: Hey, Have you given auto-layout constraints? If not, please check view hierarchy  before and after tapping tableview cell. It help to debug whether your view is misplaced on cell selection...

Comment: recently I checked the view hierarchy in this it shows tableview with its data before I select any row but when I select row, in view hierarchy every thing becomes clean only table view remains there.

Comment: Is print statement printed? What does `selectedIndexPathForCheckMark = indexPath` this code. What is logic for didSelectRow?

Comment: No print statement doesn't print. This line will be used in my next step logic. But for now I Just want when I select any row in **UITableView** my program should display its **indexparth.row** number. sorry by mistake this line also posted.

Comment: Better way delete that tableView and re add it. [Visit link and go through all solutions it may help you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255927/didselectrowatindexpath-not-being-called)

Comment: can you please write / or provide me with some example code to get this type of functionality as i told you Thank you. I also visited the link provided by you but no help

Comment: Hey Hi, I am posting code for ViewController having tableview. Its same as your code. It successfully logs didSelectRowForIndex path

Comment: Hi, its still same problem, actually what my requirement is (as I already discuss with you) that I need to have a **UITableView** when I select any `UITabbarItem` in my custom `UITabbar`(**NOT** using `UITabbarController`), I implemented this but `didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath` didn't call. I'm very sad because its not working  :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104957/discussion-between-user3314286-and-avinash-jadhav).