# UITableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath doesn't get click

Tags: ios, swift

I use for my app `UITableview` and I got a problem.
Method `tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)` called only by sliding finger from left to right or from right to left the item. But when I do normal click by this item, this method doesn't called

Comment: Did you set the delegate and datasource correctly?

Comment: I think, I did it correctly because this method gets a call but not by click)

Comment: Check this post. Maybe helps you... http://stackoverflow.com/q/255927/6124910

Comment: also didn't help :(  very strange

Comment: can't you show your code for implement data source and your delegate ?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/alym8l , http://prntscr.com/alymfa - screenshots

Comment: Did you set value single selection in selection property of tableview ?

Comment: Do you have a button or another UIControl which is hogging up tap events / touches. Try setting `UserInteractionEnabled = false;` for all content in the cell.

Comment: I changed all content inside cell to UserInteractionEnabled = false and it didn't help

Comment: I once (mistakenly) implemented `-tableView:did**Deselect**RowAtIndexPath:` instead of `-tableView:did**Select**RowAtIndexPath:` (I chose the first autocomplete candidate that popped up without reading carefully).

Answer (score 0):

What is supposed to do the cell when you click on it?. As a first impression, the line `tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: false)` is not animating the select of the cell, and that can cause the impression that nothing is happening.

Second, the implementation of the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` methods look almost the same. I mean, in both methods your are getting the same data from the `categories` array and not changing anything, at least that's what I can see with the code you provided.

Third, may the implementation of the code inside your subclass, to which `item` belongs to in `let item = categories[indexPath.row]`, be wrong.

Fourth, why your code have semicolons?.

You can review all of these to start discarding.