# TableView cell select event not triggering

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have created a component in `XIB` file. This file includes 2 components

1. Label
2. TableView

I have then linked and set it's `File's Owner` class to `SampleView`. I have attached the XIB file `view` with SampleView.swift file and this file have only following code in it's class:

```
@IBOutlet var view: UIView!
```

I have now created a controller file `SampleController` with protocols `UIViewController`, `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource`. I have placed the following code in it's `init()` func to display the custom component:

```
init() {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)

        modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Custom
        view.addSubview(SampleView())
}
```

I am using this `SampleController` to programmatically display as a `Modal`.

These codes does display as the Modal showing Label and TableView. It also populates the data in TableView. The problem is:

**When I tap the cell in table, it doesn't trigger the event on first attempt. When I tap another cell then it trigger the previous cell event.**

Any idea why is this happening?

Here are 2 functions used for populating and handling cell tap:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CELL")
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "CELL")
        }
        cell!.textLabel?.text = sampleData[indexPath.row]["title"]
        return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
       print("tapped")
}
```

Comment: Souds like a re-use of cells issue.  Have you implemented the required `UITableViewDataSource` methods? And if so, can you post them in your question?

Comment: @Koen I have mentioned that I have used UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate in `SampleController` file. Data is also populating well but the tap event is triggered after tapping the second cell.

Comment: Ok, so what's in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` functions?

Comment: @Koen I have updated the question with 2 functions.

Comment: Darn it! I was using `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` instead of `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. That's what will happen when you are programming after midnight.

Answer (score 3):

Darn it! I was using `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` instead of `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. That's what will happen when you are programming after midnight.

Comment: This is such a common mistake. Look at upvotes counts on this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/12587624/3077831

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a different method to dequeue the cell:

```
var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CELL", forIndexPath: indexPath)
```

The check for a nil cell is unnecessary, by the way.

Comment: I have received this error now: `unable to dequeue a cell with identifier CELL - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard`

Comment: Yes, you will have to fix that. Search SO and you'll find many similar problems.

Comment: That's not required when you have to create a dynamic cell and using `UITableView` instead of `UITableViewController`.