# UITableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath does not work on apple tv

Tags: uitableview, tvos, didselectrowatindexpath, apple-tv

I have a Viewcontroller that is a subclass of UITableViewController.
Basically my problem is that the delegate method is called when we're clicking on the main button:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

I have already set delegate:

```
self.tableView.delegate = self;
```

Not sure what is causing the problem. Not sure if anyone has encountered a similar issue.

Update: 
It seems long press do work. Seems there might be a conflict with a gesture recognizer somewhere. ([-didSelectRowAtIndexPath: not being called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255927/didselectrowatindexpath-not-being-called))

Answer (score 0):

You can also add segue to your cell instead of using `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`