# when i created table view programatically,didSelectRowAtIndexPath method not executed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

created table view progamatically...

```
 attatchmentTableView=[[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(attatchmentsLabel.frame.origin.x+200, attatchmentsLabel.frame.origin.y-20, issueHistoryTextView.frame.size.width, 100) ]; 

    attatchmentTableView.scrollEnabled=YES;
    //attatchmentTableView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
    attatchmentTableView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor purpleColor].CGColor;
    attatchmentTableView.allowsSelectionDuringEditing=YES;
    attatchmentTableView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0f;
    attatchmentTableView.allowsSelection=YES;
    attatchmentTableView.layer.cornerRadius=4;
    attatchmentTableView.layer.borderWidth=3.0f;
    attatchmentTableView.delegate=self;
    attatchmentTableView.dataSource=self;
   [createIssueView addSubview:attatchmentTableView];
```

and impletemented table view `datasource` and `delegate` methods, but unable to call  `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method.

So any one can help in this issuance..Thanks in advance

Comment: Update question with your "didSelectRowAtIndexPath" method.

Comment: are you added `UITableViewDelegate` in your current class

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255927/didselectrowatindexpath-not-being-called

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably it is useless, but just try to add `userinteractionenabled = true`. Or try `bringSubviewToFront`. Do you have other tableView or GestureRecongnizer?

**UPDATE**

When the `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method is not called, there many things you can check:

- `UITableViewDelegate` correctly set
- Single Selection not enabled
- Other gesture `UIGestureRecongnizer` in the same controller

In this last case, the solution depends on what you need. The fastest solution is to enable both simultaneously with this code:

```
yourGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = false;
```

Otherwise, take a look at the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`.

Comment: Try with `yourGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = false;`

Comment: `cancelsTouchesInView = false` makes `didselect` method to execute after GestureRecognizer ?

Comment: Another issue i am facing since long time...Drawing dual y-axis bar grouped bar charts..can you please help me in this issue..Thanks in advance

Comment: @vaibhav Yes, usually the GestureRecognizer is executed before the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: @ShaikTamim I'm not understanding your second question, please consider to create a new question here in SO!

Answer (score 0):

Remove these two lines and try again:

```
attatchmentTableView.allowsSelectionDuringEditing=YES;
attatchmentTableView.allowsSelection=YES;
```