# Swift didSelectRowAt on UITableView and UICollectionView not works

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionviewcell, uitableviewrowaction

I make `tableView` and `collectionView` in my `ViewController` and was set the Delegate and DataSource to my `ViewController` with extension or include the class. 
 The cell already show correctly on both of them, I haven't any `UITapGestureRecognizer` in my Class but when I want to tap on my Cell the `didSelectRowAt` not called.
 I've added `canEditRowAt` and It's work but not with `didSelectRowAt`

[image: This is my CollectionView]

[image: This is my TableView with edit action and it works]

[This is my ViewController Scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8o0LI.png)

My TableView already set :

```
- UserInteractionEnable = true 
- Selection = Single Selection
```

My Xib Files :

```
- UserInteractionEnable = true
```

This is my class :

```
class ProfileVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var profileTableView: UITableView!

    var profileTitle = DataService.instance.profileTitle

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        configureTableView()
    }

    func configureTableView() {
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "ProfileCell", bundle: nil)
        profileTableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "ProfileCell")
        profileTableView.delegate = self
        profileTableView.dataSource = self
        profileTableView.allowsSelection = true
    }

}

extension ProfileVC: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return profileTitle.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ProfileCell", for: indexPath) as? ProfileCell else { return ProfileCell() }
        cell.configureCell(withTitle: profileTitle[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("Selected")
    }

}
```

This is my ProfileCellClass :

```
class ProfileCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }

    func configureCell(withTitle title: String){
        self.titleLabel.text = title
    }   
}
```

[This my .xib file details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCRMd.png)

Thank you.

Comment: Where are you adding `profileTableView`? Are you able to scroll it?

Comment: In viewDidLoad(), ya it's bouncing when i scroll for both UITableView or UICollectionView

Comment: Can you try to implement another UITableView delegate method (like the `estimatedHeightForRowAt`) and ensure it's called?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [-didSelectRowAtIndexPath: not being called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255927/didselectrowatindexpath-not-being-called)

Comment: You don't have an IBOutlet or even an instance variable for profileTableView?

Comment: it might there is some overlay that have UserInteractionEnable = true

Comment: have you tried "CaptureViewHeirarchy" to make sure there is no overlay above your tableView

Comment: @Malloc ya it's work and my row height is changed by the value

Comment: @MattRees how cell appear if IBOutlet not connected?

Comment: @NitinGohel I just delete it and nothing change

Comment: @MuhammadNayab I've edit to my question

Comment: I am not sure whether this will resolve your issue or not but give it a try. You have registered nib in Configure TableView but you are not registering TableView Cell class i.e ProfileCell.

Comment: If he has register table view custom cell xib, then no need to register table view custom cell class. It should work fine.

Comment: What's the code inside **configureCell** method ???

Comment: @PaulMarshal just edit my question

Answer (score 0):

If your table view is in editing mode like

```
tableView.setEditing(true, animated: false)
```

you need to set

```
tableView.allowsSelectionDuringEditing = true
```

Answer (score 0):

In your ConfigureTableView method register your TableViewCell Class as well.

```
profileTableView.register(ProfileCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "ActivityImageCell")
profileTableView.register(UINib(nibName: "ProfileCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "ProfileCell")
```

This could be a reason

Comment: are you able to do any sort of interaction, like can you scroll tableView up or Down. And make sure your Gradient View stays behind the tableView.

Comment: Have you tried this 
profileTableView.allowsSelectionDuringEditing = true

Comment: ya I can, my canEditRowAt is working fine, the edit and delete is working but no with didSelectItemAt ;(