# TableView Did select not working but after long press swipe trigger the didselect method

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I have a doubt or an issue that while clicking on the tableviewCell didselect is not triggering but after long press and swipe the didselect method is triggering.I am getting this issue from last week.

[image]

The all solutions i have found in stack overflow is done but not

[image]

[image]

[image]

If any one knows what is the solution for this please comment or answer it.

Comment: Please check this answer, hope it will help you.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12855662/6255492

Comment: I have asked many developers working with me and my friends, They tell me that issue with xcode they found same issue while doing their code

Comment: Probably unrelated but if dataSource and delegate are connected in IB you can delete the corresponding lines in the code.

Comment: I have done that also but not working on that

Answer (score 0):

can you check the below code is implemented or not, if it is there remove it

```
let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: view, action: #selector(UIView.endEditing))
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
```

or verify using any gestures on this file , it will affects the didSelectRowAt methods in the tableview